# Rotate position with Photoshop animate

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, animate

I am trying to rotate a circle around another circle in Photoshop CC. I am using the transform option in the animation window. After I make the 2 keyframes. The animation isn't moving along the anchor point. Is there anyway to move the image around the circle using Photoshop animation? Would I have to do this manually?

Before

[image: before]

I then move the object based on the center of the circle.

[image: move object]

But when the animation is done. The circle doesn't move along that anchor point

[image: animation]

My first question was how to animate using transform. I then found a adobe tutorial on this. I then ran into the trouble of rotating an object around an anchor point.

The tutorial https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/photoshop-video-keyframes.html

Comment: A quick fix: make the segment a smart object as big as the background, e.g. by adding an invisible layer when creating the smart object. Then foreground and background have the same center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try this by make the curve as a "Smart Object".

Make a outer circle instead of the curve like below image

[image]

Convert the circle to smart object. Open the smart object and delete the remain parts that we don't want like below image

[image: Edit in Smart Object]

Save the smart object and close it.

Your outline curve will be come like below

[image]

Now do your creative animation even without adjusting the Pivot point.

Answer (score 0):

Another classic adobe "feature", rotation is destructive and therefore doesn't normally tween in photoshop animation. there is a way though, try this:

http://photoshopanimation.com/types-of-photoshop-animation/types-of-animation-keyframe-animation/