# How can I make a transparent PNG object spin from the center in Photoshop for a gif if the object is not a square

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, animation, gif

I've been trying to achieve this for a while now. I need to make (Image A) spin on the center point of the logo, image B (the tree point). The final should look like image C but the centre piece spinning.

I have tried the rotation effect in photoshop, but I've had two problems.

Firstly, the image I want to spin is not exactly square. So it does not spin on the centre of the windmill.

Secondly, when I did get it working, by adding pixels to the image to change the centre point, it only outputted as many images or a video format. I need it to be a gif.

**Question: How can I get image A to spin on the centre of the tree, image B to look like image C but with the blades spinning?**

IMAGE A:

[image: The object I am trying to spin]

IMAGE B:

[image: The background]

IMAGE C:

[image: The spinner object over the logo background]

Comment: Hi Austin Collins, there is a login screen to view the images, it is best to upload them into the question instead of an external link. This question is also similar to [Rotate position with Photoshop animate](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46972/rotate-position-with-photoshop-animate). And I don't really understand your second point.

Comment: @AndrewH I've updated the image links. I made the image square by adding small pixels so the centre point was in the middle of the spinner. Then it would spin without moving around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to get the spinner (Image A) to spin at the center is make the spinner a square. You have the artboard a square but when you move the PNG, it does not move based on the artboard but on the center of the spinner.

[image: Spinner is not centered in a square]

You will have to move one of the points to fit the edge of the artboard. For this, I made the right part fit to the bottom right corner to hit all 4 sides of a square.

[image: Re-made spinner]

You can see how the axis is now the center of the spinner.

To save as an animated gif, just go to save for web and select gif.

---

I am not sure how you can spin based off the center of the spinner you made since Photoshop has to transform from the center of the object.

---

**Update - If you want to use another program**

You can use a video editing program like Premier or After Effects to rotate the object. **You will still need to center the spinner** in the artboard before exporting.

I did this in Premier. Just import the file. You will find the rotation options under the effects control panel.

**To export**, File -> Exoprt -> Media -> Animated GIF

Comment: I know I need to make it square, but thats the problem, I can't. Is there any other way to make it spin, even if i can't use photoshop?

Comment: @AustinCollins See my update, you can do this in Adobe Premier or another video editing program. They will respect the artboard/canvas and not just the edges of the PNG.